# How do I learn IP of my home computer from a remote computer?

Tags: windows, ip, remote-access

I want to access web user interfaces of some of my desktop applications (like uTorrent and JDownloader) in my home computer from a remote computer. For this purpose, I need to know the IP of my home computer.

IP of my home computer is not fixed; it occasionally changes because of black outs and modem restarts. So memorizing it or keeping a note of it somewhere is not a solution. Checking for any IP changes every morning is a very bothersome solution.

Is there any tool or method for learning IP of my home computer from a remote one instantaneously?

OS (Home): Windows 7 Starter x32 SP1
OS (Remote): Windows XP or higher (Generally Windows 7)
I have full access on my home computer, but almost always have restricted access on the remote one.

Answer (score 4):

Use a dns-service like [dyndns.org](http://dyndns.org). Then you can access your computer at home via a name.

Comment: Actually some isp's will change your IP when they find DNS entries pointing to your home IP or otherwise break name resolution. They want you to buy business packages for hosting.

Comment: I think this highly depends on the location. I've no problems with things like this (in Germany).

Comment: You can use no-ip.com. As long as you set up dynamic dns in your router (if it has that option), no-ip will always update when your ip address updates.

Answer (score 1):

> Checking for any IP changes every morning is a very bothersome solution.

This is something you can automate. Have a batchfile run on startup. The commands of that file should check the IP and upload it to a place which you can consistenty reach.

Even neater would be to use DynDNS, which more or less does the same and gives you a domain name.